# Limit in discrete convolution

Tags: analysis, limits, convolution

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\{c_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{C}$ be three complex sequences and let $x_n = |a_n + b_n|$ such that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}b_n
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}c_n
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{b_n}{a_n}
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} 
\sum_{p=0}^n
x_p x_{n-p}
=
0
$$
I would like to know if is true that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\dfrac
{ 
\sum_{p=0}^n
x_p x_{n-p}
}
{
|c_n|
}
=
\lim_{n \to \infty}
\dfrac
{ 
\sum_{p=0}^n
a_p a_{n-p}
}
{
|c_n|
}
$$

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: What do you mean by $c_n$? There seems to be no conditions.

Comment: any complex sequence convergents to $0$

Comment: the question is about $x$ if i can exlude the infinitesimal $b$